# Using getfolder function to go to a default folder then select sub-folder

Tags: excel, directory, vba

I had used some code I found on here to start trying to convert a big list of Excel CSV files to Excel 2003 format. In the process of converting I wanted to open a default location folder then navigate to the right sub-folder where the CSV files are, however when stepping through the code one of my variables will not populate. My code is below and the variable that won't populate is strDir.

I'm wanting code to populate strDir with the default location + the folder that I pick, however I'm unsure what I need to do to this code to enable it to do that.

Right now I only have the default location hard-coded and when code runs, this location opens. however when I pick the sub-folder how do I record that programatically?

I know what I want to do but how to achieve this in VBA is my question.

```
Public Sub CSV_to_XLS()


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim strFile As String
Dim strDir As String
Dim strDirCapture As String

'Set base directory for get folder to manipulate csv files

strDirCapture = GetFolder("\\DEVP-APPS-07\File Storgae\1_Pending\")

'strDir = strDirCapture
strDir = strDirCapture & "\"
strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.csv")

MsgBox "String directory path = " & strDirCapture
MsgBox "StrFile = " & strFile

Do While strFile <> ""



    'Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strDir & strFile, Local:=True)
    'wb.SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".csv", ".xls"), 56 'UPDATE:
    wb.Close True

    Set wb = Nothing
    strFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub


Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Many thanks

Andrew

Update adding slash "\" to end of directory captured seems to have fixed this. Have altered code above to reflect this change.

Comment: Do you experience an error using `GetFolder` ? Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @Robin no error, it doesn't load any of the files that I want to process though. 'MsgBox "StrFile = " & strFile' shows empty. strDir takes value ok and the folder I pick is taken in but none of the files are converted to Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these lines after `strDir = strDirCapture`:

```
If Right(strDir, 1) <> "\" Then
    strDir = strDir & "\"
End If
```

Comment: I just realised this while looking at it again that slash was missing from end of directory path so added that and it worked. Thanks though for the more eloquent code you have provided above @welgen. will add that in.